# How do I recover my data on Windows machine?

Tags: 14.04, filesystem

I had some problems on my laptop,so we have taken HD from it and now we are trying to recover the data on Windows machine.Ubuntu 14.04 was installed on my laptop. How to do this? Are there any tutorials or links for this?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery  Good starting point

Comment: Did you install ubuntu on a different hard drive / partition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're getting a message on the screen asking you to format the drive when you go into Windows. That's normally the case when windows sees a unrecognised partition.

I think the best option would be to boot into a Ubuntu Live CD on a working computer, choose the option "try Ubuntu" and see if you can view your files.

If you can see your files, then you can back them up onto an external hard drive otherwise you can look into hardcore data recovery options.